# Icons in :before and :after are not getting displayed in the actual page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

I have some CSS code in a `:before` statement like this but the problem is that the Twitter icon isn't being displayed and only the block is visible but not the Twitter icon. Is the problem with my javascript, stylesheets or jQuery?

This is in `font-awesome.min.css`:

```
.icon-twitter:before { 
    content: "\f099";
}
```

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: Don't forget to add this rule: `font-family: fontawesome;

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your html as there is many factors that can cause this.

Did you include fontawesome in your html head?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Is your file path in fontawsome correct?

```
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
```

etc

Are you calling the class correctly? icon-twitter is 3.2.1

```
<i class="icon-twitter"></i>
```

The other twitter icon in 4.4.0 is called by:

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
```

There is also an IE bug where the font awesome icon will vanish if you refresh the page with F5.